# When does sum of $a_nb_n$ converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have a sum:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nb_n$$

Both of the indexes are restricted to positive, and both are real valued. Let further $a_n\rightarrow \infty,b_n \rightarrow 0$.

Question: Is there some condition under which the sum converges, preferably if and only if?

Comment: Which kind of condition are you looking for? For arbitrary $(a_n)$ you can find a sequence $(b_n)$ such that $\sum a_n b_n$ converges. (E.g. $b_n = 0$, or $b_n = a_n /n^2$, or ...)

Comment: @MartinR The most general possible condition, even better if it is provable that the sum converges if and only if the condition holds.

Comment: If you take $a_n=\ln(n) $ then no matter what $p$ we have $|a_n|^p$ doesn't converge but we can take $b_n=\frac{1}{n^2} $ then $a_nb_n$ converges.

Comment: I have now edited the question to take the observation into account. Before there was no restriction on terms apart from that they are not negative and it was shown that Hölder inequality is not a sufficient condition.

Comment: With how general this question is, I don't think there is any definitive answer since series are so finicky.